# Question about hosting Express app with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, express, web, devops

I am currently building my first production app using Express and MongoDB on the backend. My first question is what is the best bang for buck hosting service? From my research so far I think DigitalOcean looks like a great solution.

Other than this, since I never really deployed any app other than on Heroku I need some clarifications. If I were to hypothetically choose DigitalOcean, can I host both my MongoDB database and Express app on the same process? How would I connect to the database? Will I use the process IP address given to me by the hosting service or will it connect via localhost just like it does locally? Please correct me if I am totally mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well,

In Digital Ocean, a droplet is a scalable Linux-based virtual machine that runs on top of virtualized hardware. Available in a variety of distributions (Eg. Ubuntu, Fedora, CentOS, Debian, etc)

So, If you create a droplet, you essentially have a Linux VM with a specific amount of storage & memory (depends on the plan).

As you asked, you can host both MongoDB and Express App on the same process as a droplet is just a Linux instance. In that case, your Express App has access to MongoDB via `mongodb://localhost:27017`

You can also create a Droplet/Instance just for `MongoDB`

- Hypothetically, if your application scales you might have multiple VMs/instances so, having local database instances on each VM doesn't make sense. It's better to access a central source DB. Now, all your instances can access it via its IP.
- This gets even more complex when you scale further you might need to have more DB instances, backups, db load balancers etc.

Best Approach!

Using a cloud database or managed database like `MongoDB Atlas` makes much more sense. This solves all your database scalability issues, provides features like sharding, multi-cloud data distribution via AWS,Azure or GCP (As in you can choose which provider to use) etc.

You can start with a free `sandbox instance` then as requirements change, you can upgrade.

Also, explore the AWS Free Tier.

- Amazon EC2 includes 750 hours of running Linux EC2 instances (t2.micro)

Cheers!

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for MongoDB Atlas Cloud they provide free-tier managed service for database. For hosting the application I'd recommend AWS, you can make use of S3/AWS Lambda/API Gateway which all comes under free-tier for 1 whole year.

Answer (score 1):

Don't host MongoDB and your express app in the same droplet, you will have scalability issues. If it's a hobby project, then you can surely do it that way.

I will suggest you to use MongoDB atlas to host your database, it comes with many features and it's a managed database service, so you don't need to worry anything about scalability. It also has a free plan, which is good enough to get started.

You can choose a $5 droplet to host your express app and upgrade it if necessary in the future.